# no module named src

Tags: python, docker, python-module

I want to dockerize the following application, however, for some reason, I can't run it in docker, but it works on my local machine, the file structure goes as follows

```
Dockerfile
requirements.txt
src
├── database
├── logs
└── scrapers
    ├── __init__.py
    └── taskmanager.py
```

Here're the contents of my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "-m", "src.scrapers.taskmanager"]
```

For some reason, when I run the application from the root folder on my Windows machine via "python -m src.scrapers.taskmanager" it works, but that's not the case with Docker. Any help?

```
/usr/local/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'src.scrapers.taskmanager' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.scrapers')
```

Comment: Since you don't need to copy `Dockerfile` and you've already copied `requirements.txt`, can you try replacing the `COPY` with `COPY src src`?

Comment: Is there a `__init__.py` in the `src` folder?  That's necessary to make it a module.

Comment: try CMD ["python",  "src/scrapers/taskmanager.py"]